# What exactly is the meaning of gaining visibility in office?

Tags: career-development

What exactly is the meaning of gaining visibility in office? I have heard lot of senior people and other colleagues in office mention about this. If it is related to creating your strong positive impression at the workplace, how  different is it from having a good reputation? Does gaining visibility take the same time like creating a good reputation. Since this is very commonly used word and at the same time, not part of formal education, I want to know what exactly is this concept of Visibility(, its origin if possible) and how important it is from a career context, and how is it useful for the project/company, if at all?

I am a Software developer, and my job involves a reasonable amount of individual focused work with a computer compared to interacting with people and communicating, as compared to someone in lets say Sales or Marketing. How important it is from different careers' point of view?

**Adding an example context if someone wants to know:-**

Suppose we are a business unit, where there are two teams

Team A with a commonly found skill-set, but works as a single team with all responsibility in one location

Team B with a highly specialized skill-set but responsibility and sub-teams split across multiple locations.

Somehow, the people in team A are more known to people in the higher management and people in team B although being more valuable from the skill point of view, struggle to be talked about as much as team A by higher management. When asked why this is the case, many colleagues say, team A has more visibility. This is just a context for those who want some clarity. Question however is generic

Comment: Can you add some context? In that context have you heard this said

Comment: @Bee Added context in the question

Answer (score 3):

> If it is related to creating your strong positive impression at the
>   workplace, how different is it from having a good reputation?

You could have a good reputation with your boss and a couple of people in the company, but in a large company, that doesn't mean every department knows you.

> Does gaining visibility take the same time like creating a good reputation.

It depends.

For instance, if there are two projects in your company. One project is exciting, the technology is brand new, there is a lot of hype surrounding that technology, and the project itself could potentially earn your company millions, but the second project is less exciting, it's a legacy system, and it's an internal system to automate a part of HR (which is not revenue-generating to the company).

The first project would get you noticed by the CEO and other executives. The second project, however, would probably only get noticed by a few HR employees. So gaining visibility means that you have to choose the right projects to work on, but gaining visibility can also mean a ton of other things too.

One boss I had gained visibility in his industry by organizing and hosting industry-related meetings at our company. He was then able to leverage that visibility into getting the job of CEO at another (much smaller) company.

Some software developers I know gained visibility in their industry by publishing open-source [projects](https://square.github.io/) and giving talks under the banner of their company. For that, you obviously need to have a company willing to have its employees do that. Some companies act the opposite way. Once they hire someone good, they don't want that person to give any technical talk for fear that someone else will poach that person from them.

But at the most basic level, being able to gain visibility means that you're also a good public speaker. For that, I'd recommend that you join a [Toastmasters](http://www.toastmasters.org/) public speaking club. They're almost [everywhere](http://www.toastmasters.org/find-a-club). And since the organization itself is a non-profit, the membership fee is very nominal. Just don't join the first club you find. Visit a couple before you make up your mind. They can all be very different.

> How important it is from different careers' point of view?

Being a good worker. Having a good reputation. That's your foundation. Having a good foundation is extremely important. But if you want to be a top earner in your field, gaining visibility (assuming that you're already a good worker) is also extremely important.

And I suppose that gaining visibility would be more important in sales and in marketing than it would be in developing software, but that's only because our society rewards salespeople more.

Answer (score 1):

A good reputation and Visibility have many overlaps in my opinion. A good reputation will give you visibility in the company.

Visibility means (IMHO) that people within the company  know what you do and what are your skills and is your knowledge and they know they can contact you when they have problems questions or opportunities that require your skills or knowledge.

So you would need a good reputation within your company for your skills and knowledge and you need to be approachable when they need your help. Because if there is someone with slightly less knowledge but a lot easier to approach, chances are they will go to them.

What it means exactly for your situation more context is needed.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think it's helpful to equate a good reputation with visibility. Firstly, one can be visible and have a bad reputation. Secondly, one can have a reasonably good reputation yet be almost entirely invisible.

Comment: @perenniallydisappointed I agree with your second part. Thats what I meant to say by being approachable. Visibility has two parts. Although the first statement is also true, this is ofcourse not what anyone mean when they ask you to be more visible and that is what OP asked.